# How to custom sort-out editing-panel fields?

Tags: posts, custom-field, editor

I'm developing a theme for newspaper. For some new fields like: Top Sub Heading, Bottom Sub Heading, Reporter's Name etc., I implemented custom fields (For a handy use of custom fields, I used the "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin - that's not an issue)

So now, for a site editor the WordPress editing fields are like the following images, scattered in different places:
[image]

We know the WordPress editing panel is by default like:

```
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" value="" id="title">
<textarea class="wp-editor-area" cols="40" name="content" id="content" aria-hidden="true"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" value="Publish" accesskey="p">
```

I want to rearrange the input fields in a way that, I can put them in a common place serially like:

1. *Categories `<select><option></option></select>`
2. Top-Sub Title (my custom field input field) `<input type="text"/>`
3. *Post/News Title `<input type="text"/>`
4. Bottom Sub Title (my custom field input field) `<input type="text"/>`
5. Reporter (my custom field input field) `<input type="text"/>`
6. *Post/News Description `<textarea><textarea/>`

```
* WordPress default editor fields
```

So that it would look like:

[image: I want to rearrange the editing panel's input fields]

## Is that possible?

Comment: _"Is that possible?"_ ... depends on what the "Advanced Custom Fields"-plugin can deliver. But in general: Yes. So, what's the actual question aside from this?

Comment: It's not actually a plugins related question. I want to sort 'em out - that's it. If that can be possible, then I won't use any plugin, I will make some input fields and make them feasible for associated custom fields. Then no plugins will be required. Na? Thank you for your attention @kaiser.

Comment: So is your question "how do I do this without using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin"?

Comment: I mentioned about Advanced Custom Fields Plugin because it made for me a good looking editor panel - that's it. There is no connection with the plugin with my question. :)

Comment: @kaiser: Any idea... you said *"But in general: Yes."*

Comment: Still don't get your questions...

Comment: Ok, I better edit the question without the plugin matters...

Comment: Edited the question with images and more details. Thanks.

Comment: Got something **[HERE](http://www.farinspace.com/move-and-position-wordpress-visual-editor/)** but isn't working here, as can't enqueue jQuery for Admin panel. Can't try with this any further. :(

Comment: You should totally drop all that and try [tag:jQuery] instead :) Could work! On the other hand, to put your own meta boxes *after* the Title field, use the hook [edit_form_after_title](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=edit_form_after_title).